# Improve jQuery snippet for non DRY

Tags: jquery

I have a Jquery snippet that works fine with my image-map that is making a mouseover on map when hover on navigation menu.
But I have to use the code over and over again (DRY) on every id or class.
Here is my jQuery code on jsfiddle but I haven't made it work in jsfiddle.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h1kzgetu/3/).

```
<a id="hoverlink1" href="#">mouse over this to trigger a hilight from an external element!</a>
<br />
<a id="hoverlink2" href="#">mouse over this to trigger a hilight from an external element!</a>
<br />
<a id="hoverlink3" href="#">mouse over this to trigger a hilight from an external element!</a>
<br />

<div id="hover1">hover this id</div>
<div id="hover2">hover this id</div>
<div id="hover3">hover this id</div>
```

This code is what I have now and it works but i have to do DRY on everey id

```
    $('#hoverlink1').mouseover(function(e) {
        $('#hover1').mouseover();
    }).mouseout(function(e) {
        $('#hover1').mouseout();
    }).click(function(e) { e.preventDefault(); });
```

Maybe it should look more like this.
This one dosen't work it is only an idea from me

```
    $(this).data('id').mouseover(function(e) {
                var target = $(this).data("target");
                $(target).mouseover();
            }).mouseout(function(e) {
                var target = $(this).data("target");
                $(target).mouseout();
            })
```

Is there a way to improve this so I don't have to DRY

Comment: There's such a thing called "classes", they can be used on multiple elements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add a common class to each hoverlink, then you can use that class to install one event handler on all the objects.  That event handler can then parse the number out of the hoverlink id to construct the corresponding hover id like this:

```
$(".hoverlink").on("mouseenter mouseleave", function(e) {
    var num = this.id.match(/\d+$/)[0];
    var color = e.type === "mouseenter" ? "red" : "black";
    $("#hover" + num).css("color", color);
}).on("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/o0y94bhm/

I didn't really understand what you were trying to do when the link was hovered so I hooked up just a simple color change to make the functioning of the code visible, but you can obviously insert whatever code you want there.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `class` instead.  While `id`s should be unique within a page, `class`es can be all over the place.

HTML

```
<a id="hoverlink1" class="hoverDelegate" data-target="hover1" href="#">mouse over this to trigger a hilight from an external element!</a>
<br />
<a id="hoverlink2" class="hoverDelegate" data-target="hover2" href="#">mouse over this to trigger a hilight from an external element!</a>
<br />
<a id="hoverlink3" class="hoverDelegate" data-target="hover3" href="#">mouse over this to trigger a hilight from an external element!</a>
<br />

<div id="hover1">hover this id</div>
<div id="hover2">hover this id</div>
<div id="hover3">hover this id</div>
```

jQuery

```
$('.hoverDelegate').on({
    mouseover: function (e) {
        var delegateId = $(this).data('target');

        $('#' + delegateId).mouseover();
    },
    mouseout: function (e) {
        var delegateId = $(this).data('target');

        $('#' + delegateId).mouseover();
    },
    click: function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```